# webclient download file but not perform completed

Tags: c#, wpf, download, webclient

I don't want to use downloadfileAsync event i used downloadfile any completed event is there, for only downloadfile, any ideas or any other way than tell me Thank you in advance.

```
  if (!item.IsInstalled && item.IsChecked)
                    {
                        string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "AlisAppTemp", "Silverlight");
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("Error");
                        }

                        client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
                        client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;
                        client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/8/C/F8C0EACB-92D0-4722-9B18-965DD2A681E9/30514.00/Silverlight_x64.exe"), filename);
                        item.IsDownloaded = true;
                    }


 private void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double byteIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = byteIn / totalBytes * 100;
            DownloadData = "Download " + e.BytesReceived / 1024 + " Of " + e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024;
            this.CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.UserState != null && e.UserState is AlisApplicationModel)
            {
                AlisApplicationModel ObjApp = e.UserState as AlisApplicationModel;
                ObjApp.IsDownloaded = true;
            }
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                this.Cleanup();

            }
            //if (!_bw.IsBusy)
            //{
            //    _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            //}

        }
```

Comment: @whatever which reason you down vote just give reason and then downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DownloadFileCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DownloadProgressChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events will be raised **only** for **asynchronous** downloads.

You're using synchronous `DownloadFile` method, so your `client_DownloadProgressChanged` and `client_DownloadFileCompleted` methods will never be called.

So you have to use `DownloadFileAsync` instead of `DownloadFile` method.

Comment: so if i use download file synchronous so i can't update my progress bar ? it's complesory to use downloadfileAsync event ?

Comment: Yes. If you're using `DownloadFile` (note this is method, not event as you called it) - then `DownloadProgressChanged` and `DownloadFileCompleted` events will not be raised. You **have** to use `DownloadFileAsync` if you want to handle these events.

Comment: @Dhru'soni By the way - is there any reason for you to dislike usage of `DownloadFileAsync` and prefer `DownloadFile`?

Comment: Actually m using process installation of silverlight in background but when i started check and install bot process running together and when m using download file that will perfectly execute. but i can't update progress. as u say i have to use downloadfileAsync dats the only way.